# Problems with mapping user ids back to their respective cluster class in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I did clustering and now want to map the cluster_class to each 'userid' row in my original dataframe. However, my past part of the code for "mapping" does NOT return the dataframe which I am expecting.

```
df=
userid       recency     frequency
1233         33232.0     5.715858
3344         23403.0     3.615858

#convert df to array
data=data.values
X=data

    #Scale
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

    # Compute DBSCAN
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.25, min_samples=10).fit(X)
    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = db.labels_

    # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

    #get dataframe with cluster_class and its data size

    df=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(labels).value_counts())
    df.index.names = ['Cluster_Class']
    df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "Users" }, inplace = True)

df=

Users    Cluster_Class  
0        2096
-1       30
2        13
1        11

#MAP each cluster class to all userids. NOT WORKING!!!

    N_CLUSTERS = len(df.index.names)-1
    clusters = [X[db == i] for i in range(N_CLUSTERS)]

    for i, c in enumerate(clusters):
        print('Cluster {} has {} members: {}...'.format(i, len(c), c[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the labels.

But you compare the clustering object of type DBSCAN  to an integer.